Where do i find data about the Kamov Ka 50?
I am a student in Aerospatial Engineering and i have to make a project about this helicopter. Professor asked for some data like: Rotor blade airfoil, Rotor blade width at the beginning and tip of it, at what height can it safely land just with autorotation, and so on. I have no idea where to get this data from, can someone help?

Hi and welcome to Aviation. Unfortunately resource location questions are off topic here.

I can pretty much guarantee, that data about the exact airfoil or dimensions etc. is not publicly available but rather classified information, as it would allow to calculate classified performance data of this military helicopter.
That being said, you can make good guestimates from photos which you can find on the internet. Especially root and tip chord and similar data can be extracted from photos which also show known dimensions. Perhaps you can also look at some photos of the blades and "guestimate" the airfoil. You could also assume that this helicopter has the same airfoils as other helicopters. For example, the Bölkow Bo-105 has NACA 23012 airfoils, so perhaps it is safe to assume that the Kamov KA 50 has this or a similar airfoil? I would bet that there is not much difference.
